# RegEx - Don't match if inner HTML tags exist

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have put together a regex (see below) and am having trouble only matching if NO inner html tags exist

Examples:

`<b>asdf</b>` <= This should match

`<b>asdf<i>asdf</i></b>` <= This should NOT match

`<b>asdf<i></b>` <= This should NOT match

**My Regex**: `/<([b])>(.+?)</([b])>/g`
Please see this [link](https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=104078)

Can someone point me in the right direction to ensure that the regex does not match if there are inner HTML tags?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . You probably don't want to be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you posted, the first problem is `/` has a special meaning (regex boundaries) and needs to be escaped. Then, if I understand correctly, you want to match `<b>` tags with text only inside. One basic way would be to discard anything with `<`:

```
 /<(b)>([^<]+)<\/(b)>/
```

(side notes: `b` doesn't need to be inside `[]`; except if you want grouping, parentheses can also be dropped, leading to: `/<b>[^<]+<\/b>/`)

Now, we usually avoid regexes for parsing/striping HTML, as a brilliant answer to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) explains.

In javascript, there are many ways of getting hold on text only without regexes. For examples, see [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to use a regular expression for this, you can simplify yours considerably: match `<b>`, followed by anything but an opening angle bracket, followed by `</b>`:

```js
const re = /<b>[^<]+<\/b>/;
const str = `Aenean lacinia bibendum <a href="/life">life</a> sed consectetur. <a href="/work">Work</a> quis risus eget urna mollis ornare <a href="/about">about</a> leo. <a><asdf>asdf</asdf></a> <a>asdf</a>

This should not match:
<b><i>asdf</i></b>

This should match:
<b>asdf</b>`;
console.log(str.match(re));
```